# Function overloading error: TS7006:Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

Here is an example of the function overloading which is published on the official [website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) :

```
let suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];

function pickCard(x: {suit: string; card: number; }[]): number;
function pickCard(x: number): {suit: string; card: number; };
function pickCard(x): any {
    // Check to see if we're working with an object/array
    // if so, they gave us the deck and we'll pick the card
    if (typeof x == "object") {
        let pickedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length);
        return pickedCard;
    }
    // Otherwise just let them pick the card
    else if (typeof x == "number") {
        let pickedSuit = Math.floor(x / 13);
        return { suit: suits[pickedSuit], card: x % 13 };
    }
}
```

When I put this code to my working typscript file i get error:

> Error:(5, 19) TS7006:Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How to make this example to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you probably have the `noImplicitAny` flag on.
In this case you can either do:

```
function pickCard(x: any): any {
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
function pickCard(x: number | {suit: string; card: number; }[]): any {
    ...
}
```